# SQL select from more tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, database-table

Good day,

I have 2 sql tables.

```
Plaatsen

 - plid
 - x
 - y
```

and

```
Reservations

 - id
 - plid
 - startdate
 - enddate
```

plid in reservations has a foreign key to Plaatsen.plid

What i want is :

I got 1 date (for example 2013-12-09) how can i find all plid's that are not in the table Reservations on that variabel date? so it is not between startdate and enddate

Is this possible? can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Plaatsen WHERE plid NOT IN (SELECT plid from Reservations where :date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)
```

Where `:date` is your control date. Don't be afraid of subquerys, SQL servers have good optimizations for it.

Comment: can you make a query where i see all plid from plaatsen where reservation are between dates. so instead of using 1 date use between 2 dates ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Plid FROM Plaatsen p 
LEFT JOIN Reservations R ON P.Plid=R.Plid 
WHERE '2013-12-09' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND R.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This won't return any rows. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out why.